# Angular 2 map response from Facebook Graph Api

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting the posts from a Facebook page using http calls to the Graph Api.

The code where I get the array of posts is:

```
let url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/15087023444/posts?fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true),type,message,created_time,link,name,caption,description,attachments{subattachments,media,type}&limit=10';

return this.http
    .get(url, requestOptions)
    .map(response => response.json())
```

The response has a `data` array with the posts and a `paging` object with the pagination urls.

Here's an example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "video",
      "message": "Debate This. Kevin Durant is now a world champion. #NikeBasketball",
      "created_time": "2017-06-13T03:48:09+0000",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/nike/videos/10155067082768445/",
      "attachments": {
        "data": [
          {
            "media": {
              "image": {
                "height": 316,
                "src": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t15.0-10/19144894_10155067101998445_7200648628933754880_n.jpg?oh=a5280076d9790c89fe97b144992f68c1&oe=59DFA425",
                "width": 600
              }
            },
            "type": "video_autoplay"
          }
        ]
      },
      "id": "15087023444_10155067082768445"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5QXhOVEE0TnpBeU16UTBORG90TVRVMk5UUTROelV5TlRjNU9UVTROVGc0TWc4TVlYQnBYM04wYjNKNVgybGtEeDB4TlRBNE56QXlNelEwTkY4eE1ERTFOVEEyTnpBNE1qYzJPRFEwTlE4RWRHbHRaUVpaUDJCNUFRPT0ZD",
      "after": "Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5QXhOVEE0TnpBeU16UTBORG90TVRVMk5UUTROelV5TlRjNU9UVTROVGc0TWc4TVlYQnBYM04wYjNKNVgybGtEeDB4TlRBNE56QXlNelEwTkY4eE1ERTFOVEEyTnpBNE1qYzJPRFEwTlE4RWRHbHRaUVpaUDJCNUFRPT0ZD"
    },
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/15087023444/posts?access_token=EAACEdEose0cBALc3s7rQrG3c3gT6rKzb7ATiu9hj18T3sgxLPEBrF3U5b0SJ8uP3kGJne4PPS6KpsLiiQiSLVmZAhY5W1gj7JvEAflL55K1tcWHLDUbmTnyrIN0HZBJkp6u6zziSmWWWqGeEEJlZCaGR52xisCWJ92Hr9GkUJx0T7MS1tnQZAjVNv3GH5sYZD&pretty=0&fields=likes.limit%280%29%2Ccomments.limit%280%29%2Ctype%2Cmessage%2Ccreated_time%2Clink%2Cname%2Ccaption%2Cdescription%2Cattachments%7Bsubattachments%2Cmedia%2Ctype%7D&limit=1&after=Q2c4U1pXNTBYM0YxWlhKNVgzTjBiM0o1WDJsa0R5QXhOVEE0TnpBeU16UTBORG90TVRVMk5UUTROelV5TlRjNU9UVTROVGc0TWc4TVlYQnBYM04wYjNKNVgybGtEeDB4TlRBNE56QXlNelEwTkY4eE1ERTFOVEEyTnpBNE1qYzJPRFEwTlE4RWRHbHRaUVpaUDJCNUFRPT0ZD"
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is map this response in order to get these two values (`data` array and `paging` object) into two separate variables that can be used in the view.
Something like this gets the data array and assigns it to an observable:

```
public posts: Observable<any[]>;

this.posts = this.facebookProvider
      .getPosts(this.pageId)
      .map(data => data['data'].map(this.mapPosts))
```

And the mapPosts function:

```
mapPosts = (post) => {
    return {
      id: post.id
      message: post.message,
      attachments: post.attachments,
      likes: post.likes.summary.total_count,
      comments: post.comments.summary.total_count
    };
  }
```

How can I get the `paging` object and assign it to a variable?
Is there a way to achieve this without two separate calls to the api?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally  your component will subscribe values from the service.

if your just displaying value than you don't need Observable `public posts: Observable<any[]>;`

you can use normal variable like `public posts : any[] = [];`

```
 this.facebookProvider
      .getPosts(this.pageId).subscribe(data => {
 this.posts = data['data'].map(this.mapPosts);
this.paging = data.paging}
```

);

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. Just noticed that the async pipe I was using in the ngFor stopped working. Removing the pipe works fine. Do you think the async pipe can still be used or it's not necessary?

Comment: if your just displaying data than you don't need use Async pipe. if your directly using observable from service than you need use Async pipe.check this link http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-async-pipe-example